# Make a sequence an increasing sequence by adding a number multiple times

Tags: java, algorithm

I have an array of numbers, now I want to make this as increasing sequence by adding a fixed number `b`. I want to find how many times the fixed number `b` is added to make my array as increasing sequence.

Here is the program which is working:

```
int process(int[] a, int b) {
    int count = 0;

   for (int i = 0; i + 1 < a.length; i++) {
        int current = a[i];
        int next = a[i + 1];

        // add b to next element if it is less than current  
        while (next <= current) {
            next += b;
            count++;
        }
        a[i + 1] = next;
    }
    return count;
}
```

**Example:**

```
    int[] a = { 1, 3, 3, 2 };
    int B = 2;
    Output is 3
```

**Explanation:**

a[1] = 3 & a[2] = 3, so increment a[2] by B so a[2] = 3+2 = 5

Now a[2] = 5 & a[3]=2, so incremease a[3] by multiple of B so it is more than a[2], so a[3] = 2 + 2*2 = 6

So we have incremented 3 times, so the output is 3.

**The time complexity of this program is O(N^2), but I was asked to reduce the time complexity of this program further. What is the better approach?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should solve the problem in O(n):

```
int process(int[] a, int b) {
    int count = 0, dif = 0, add = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
        dif = a[i] - a[i - 1];
        if(dif < 0){
            dif = Math.abs(dif);
            add = (dif / b);
            if(a[i - 1] + (add * b) >= a[i]) add++;
            a[i] += add * b;
            count += add;
        }
        else if(dif == 0){
            a[i] += b;
            count ++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

The idea is to take the difference between adjacent numbers and evaluate how many `B`s you need to add, which is the difference divided by `B`.

If adjacent numbers are equal, just add a single `B`.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if(a[i] == a[i - 1])` instead of `else if(dif == 0)` in order to achieve strictly increasing sequences? Consider the example `int[] a = { 1, 3, 3, 2 }` and `int B = 1`: Your code is producing the sequence `1 3 4 4` (3) while the OP's code is producing `1 3 4 5` (4).

Comment: Yes, in fact there was this problem. I fixed it. The `dif` thing was not the main issue.